# Cast N1QLQuery response into custom object in Scala

Tags: scala, couchbase, sql++

I have a simple `case class`:

```
case class Account(accountId: Long, login: DateTime)
```

Now I want to retrieve docs from Couchbase bucket by simple N1QL query (it should return a simple list of JSON documents contain two fields):

```
val query = "SELECT u.accountId, u.login FROM `accounts` u WHERE DATE_DIFF_STR(NOW_STR(), u.login, 'day') > 30"
bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(query)).map(rows => rows.map(row => row.value().asInstanceOf[Account]).seq)
```

but, I got an error there in postman:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject cannot be cast to com.package.account
```

My question is - how I could cast docs from database into my, custom object? I also tried to cast it into `RawJSONDocument` first, but it did not help. 
Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Have you tried to parse the json using json library? If you call `toString` on the JsonObject you will get a string repr which you can parse with something like circe. Have a look [here](https://medium.com/@djoepramono/how-to-parse-json-in-scala-c024cb44f66b) on how to get started with this. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

First, you may be interested to know that we're actively working on a native Couchbase Scala SDK at present for release this year, and it will support your use case of converting rows directly into a case class.

But in the here-and-now, no you cannot directly cast a JsonObject into a case class.  You will need to use `toString` to pull out the raw JSON string, and then use a Scala JSON library to convert it.  You've got several options here:

**Jackson**

```
    val json = row.value().toString()
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    val account = mapper.readValue(json, classOf[Account])
```

**uPickle**

```
    val account = upickle.default.read[Account](json)
```

**Jsoniter**

```
    val account = com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.core.readFromString[Account](json)
```

Plus there's Circe, Json4s, Play Json, Jawn etc..

FWIW, I found Jsoniter to be the fastest in my benchmarking.